# Clear form after submitting with vuex

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to clear a `form` after I submit it, in this case creating a simple user. I am resetting the state with `vuex` (see below). But the form stays with data.

this is how the form looks like

```
<form @submit.prevent="onSubmit" v-if="!loading">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input placeholder="Name" v-model="user.name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
            <span class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.name">{{ errors.name }}</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input v-bind:class="{ harError: errors.email }" placeholder="Email" v-model="user.email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="validationCustom03">
            <span class="invalid-feedback" v-if="errors.email">{{ errors.email }}</span>
        </div>
...
```

the onSubmit method

```
          /**
           * on submitting the form  update or crete a user
           */
          onSubmit() {
              let action = this.id ? 'UPDATE_USER' : 'CREATE_USER';
              this.inProgress = true;
              this.$store
                  .dispatch(action)
                  .then(() => {
                      console.log('reset or not?');
                      this.inProgress = false;
                      // navigate to user
                      this.$router.push('users');
                  })
                  .catch( ({ response }) => {
                      this.inProgress = false;
                      this.errors = response.data.errors;
                      console.log('you have an error on creating an user')
                    });
            },
```

Resetting the

```
        RESET_STATE({state}) {
            console.log('reset state');
            for (let f in state) {
                Vue.set(state, f, initialState[f]);
            }
        },
```

the state like this

```
const initialState = {
    users: [],
    user: {
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        type: '',
        bio: '',
        photo: '',
        active: '1',
    },
    loading: false,
};

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    state: { ...initialState },
...
```

The `input` types stais with data

[image]

Comment: Probably because you are doing a shallow copy in `state: { ...initialState }`. I suggest you turn `initialState` into a function and call it when needed.

Comment: it's not before I did this change I still had this problem, also I just returned just to check and yeah It's not that one

Comment: Can you add `onSubmit` methods on your question?

Comment: @Owl Yes, I just did that. thanks for mentioning

Comment: Please also add UPDATE_USER and CREATE_USER vuex actions

Comment: Have you tried the reset function of javascript? Something like this: document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

Answer (score 0):

Ok At least I figured out myself, Insead of a `const` I used a function to set the `initialtState` like so

```
function initialState () {
    return {
        users: [],
        user: {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            type: '',
            bio: '',
            photo: '',
            active: '1',
        },
        loading: false,
    }
}
```

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    namespaced: true,
    state: { ...initialState() },
```

then in the `mutations` i assigned the `intitialState` to the `state`

```
   mutations: {
       /**
         *
         * @param state
         * @constructor
         */
        RESET_STATE: (state) => {
            Object.assign(state, initialState())
        },
```

in my user component I dispached it like so

```
  ...mapActions(['RESET_STATE']),

...

this.$store.dispatch("RESET_STATE");
```